# Is there a way to change the stylesheet of just OK button of all the QMessageBox?

Tags: python, qt5, pyside2, qtstylesheets

I would like to have the OK button of all the `QMessageBox` of my GUI (which is quite complex and so there are a lot of them) set a different color with respect to the other buttons (Cancel, No etc.).

I don't want to set its color every time I create a new `QMessageBox` but I would like to set it through the stylesheet of my application once and for all.

I tried different options but none of them worked:

```
 - QMessageBox#okButton {background-color:blue}
 - QMessageBox::okButton {...}
 - QMessageBox:okButton {...}
 - QMessageBox#ok-button {...}
 - QMessageBox QPushButton#okButton {...}
```

and others...

Is there a way or do I have to give up?

Comment: Are those message boxes created with static methods? If that's so, unfortunately you can't, unless, not with certainty: the only way to style buttons of a QMessageBox created with static method is to use the property selector based on the text, but that's only a guess, based on the style and on the localization; a "Cancel" button could be "Annulla" in Italian or "Abbrechen" in German, and in any case it could have a mnemonic and you cannot be sure about it: even in English, it could be "&Cancel" or "C&ancel" and so on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no direct solution, since QDialogButtonBox (which is what QMessageBox uses for its buttons) doesn't provide selectors for button roles.

For staticly created messagebox, the only way is to use the `[text="button text"]` selector, but that would just be a guess, which could change depending on the localization and the style (which could set a mnemonic, and you cannot even know what that would be for sure). Also, this requires setting the stylesheet for the QApplication.

A possible application wide stylesheet for these situations would look like this:

```
app.setStyleSheet('''
    QDialogButtonBox > QPushButton[text="&OK"] {
        background-color: orange;
    }
    QDialogButtonBox > QPushButton[text="&Cancel"] {
        background-color: green;
    }
''')
```

Note that I used the `Parent > Class` selector in order to ensure that only buttons of QDialogButtonBox are styled with those rules, otherwise *any* "Ok" button would be orange, etc.

Nonetheless, in the case above on my computer it only works for the Ok button, since my localization (Italian) uses "&Annulla" for the other.

On the other hand, if you're creating QMessageBox instances, there's more freedom and flexibility using selectors based on object names.

The only issue is that since the object name is set *after* the creation, the stylesheet is not applied, so the buttons must be "unpolished" after instantiation.

A simple subclass could provide a standard interface without complicating things too much:

[image: colored buttons]

```
class ColoredMessageBox(QtWidgets.QMessageBox):
    StandardNames = {
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok: 'Ok', 
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel: 'Cancel', 
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Save: 'Save', 
        # ...
    }
    def exec_(self):
        for button in self.buttons():
            objName = self.StandardNames.get(self.standardButton(button))
            if objName:
                button.setObjectName(objName)
            self.style().unpolish(button)
        return super().exec_()

import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet('''
    QMessageBox > QDialogButtonBox > QPushButton#Ok {
        background-color: orange;
    }
    QMessageBox > QDialogButtonBox > QPushButton#Cancel {
        background-color: blue;
    }
''')
w = ColoredMessageBox(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Information, 'Hello', 'How are you?', 
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel)
w.exec_()
```

Comment: I ended up using your solution, the simplest one: using text selectors. That's because I use staticly created MessageBox. I have no problems and everything works fine...for the moment. I previously used eyllanesc solution but after some months I started to get some very strange errors coming from the Application class. Grazie (I'm italian too)!

Answer (score 5):

A possible solution is to set the `objectName()` to be a selector for each button and for this you can use the `notify()` method of the `QApplication`:

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import QEvent
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class Application(QApplication):
    def notify(self, receiver, event):
        if isinstance(receiver, QMessageBox) and event.type() == QEvent.Show:
            for button in receiver.buttons():
                sb = receiver.standardButton(button)
                if not button.objectName():
                    button.setObjectName(sb.name.decode())
                    button.style().unpolish(button)
                    button.style().polish(button)
        return super().notify(receiver, event)


def main():
    app = Application()
    app.setStyle("fusion")

    app.setStyleSheet(
        """
    QPushButton#Ok { background-color: green }
    QPushButton#Cancel { background-color: red }
    """
    )

    QMessageBox.critical(
        None, "Title", "text", buttons=QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel
    )

    msgBox = QMessageBox()
    msgBox.setText("The document has been modified.")
    msgBox.setInformativeText("Do you want to save your changes?")
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
    msgBox.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution, I never thought about using `notify` for this, which also automatically solves the issue with static functions.